# PCI onsite QSA Audit Review

Tags: audit, pci-dss

Has anyone had any success using video recordings from ObserveIT during a PCI  onsite QSA audit review?  We are scheduled to be audited in a few months and are considering adding ObserveIT to guarantee coverage of anything missing. Is this a good expectation?

Answer (score 2):

You should be asking this question directly to your QSA as they will be determining what they accept as evidence for your compliance. The PCI Council does not necessarily bless or damn any particular application, if you find a tool that will help you easily manage or address a requirement, and its cost effective and accepted by the QSA, you'd have a win.